# MYSQL: How to get hours logged by week

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there are similar questions out there on this topic, but I cannot seem to get the right output I need.

I have a table called "Time"

Within this table, are the attributes TimeId, TimeAmount, TimeDate, and FK_TaskId.

I need a query that sums the TimeAmount by week (Starting on Monday and ending on Sunday).

Here is some data thats in the table:

```
TaskID TimeAmount TimeDate TaskId

1         250      8/16/2015    1

2         234      8/17/2015    2

3         356      8/15/2015    3

4         345      8/16/2015    3
```

The query I have, that does not display anything but null values:

```
SELECT TimeDate as "Week", SUM(TimeAmount) AS "Total Time"
FROM time
WHERE YEARWEEK(TimeDate) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE());
```

Thanks in advance for all the help, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What data-type is `TimeAmount`?

Comment: The data type is VARCHAR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do

```
SELECT
YEARWEEK(STR_TO_DATE(TimeDate, '%m/%d/%Y')) as Week, 
SUM(TimeAmount) AS "Total Time"
FROM time
GROUP BY 1
```

**Update**

If you have TimeDate as a `DATE`-column you can do

```
SELECT
YEARWEEK(TimeDate) as Week, 
SUM(TimeAmount) AS "Total Time"
FROM time
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Why does that work? Is varchar not a good data type to use for dates? Also, what if I wanted to sum the time from the current week only?

Comment: does it work? No, VARCAHR is a bad datatype to store dates. In your case it would take 10 bytes per value. If you convert the coltype to `DATE` it would need 3 bytes per value and you could use MySQL Date-functions without casting the value by STR_TO_DATE...

Comment: But be careful in the conversion: MySQL default date-format is yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: I'll just change the data type to DATE.  I don't have a whole lot of data yet so it wont be a big deal.  Can you alter your answer if the data type was DATE instead of VARCHAR